# Highcharts modal editor not working perfectly when we scroll the page before opening the modal editor

Tags: highcharts-editor

I have a button in my project and when the user clicks on this button, the highcharts modal editor is opened. but when the user made any scroll on the page before clicking on the button, then the modal editor should show some design issues.
But this issue exists in the highcharts modal editor live demo also when we made a scroll on the page before clicking on the button.
[this is an issue after I click the "CREATE A CHART" button in the live demo after a scroll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7KqhZ.png)
Can anyone help me to fix this one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a file `highcharts-editor.min.css` in your `highcharts-editor` directory. Search for class .`highed-dropdown-items` in that class you can see

```
**position : fixed;**
```

change that to

```
**position: absolute;**
```

This will fix your issue for sure

Comment: thank you @RoNs JoN, it is working fine, you saved my day....